# Why does CONCAT'ed value in MariaDB query result in Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_bin,NONE) collation?

Tags: sql, collation, mariadb-10.3, character-set

We have a query that CONCATs a bunch of values together, and then searches against it, and we're getting this error:

```
Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_bin,NONE) and (utf8mb4_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'like'
```

The strange thing is that on one RDS instance the error does not occur and on another it does.  Both instances are running MariaDB 10.3, and i've checked and both databases are default charset `utf8mb4` and default collation `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`.

To troubleshoot, i've run a modified query that just calls CHARSET() and COLLATION() on the CONCAT'ed value.  And low and behold, on the instance that's throwing an error that results in `CHARSET=utf8mb4, COLLATION=utf8mb4_bin` and on the instance that the query runs ok on that results in `CHARSET=utf8mb4, COLLATION=utf8mb4_unicode_ci`.

The CONCAT looks like this:

```
CONCAT_WS(', '
    ,CASE WHEN SUM((`table1`.`View`)) <> 0 THEN CONCAT('View(', CAST(SUM((`table1`.`View`)) AS CHAR) ,')') ELSE NULL END
    ,CASE WHEN SUM((`table1`.`Edit`)) <> 0 THEN CONCAT('Edit(', CAST(SUM((`table1`.`Edit`)) AS CHAR) ,')') ELSE NULL END
    ,CASE WHEN SUM((`table1`.`Add`)) <> 0 THEN CONCAT('Add(', CAST(SUM((`table1`.`Add`)) AS CHAR) ,')') ELSE NULL END
    , CONCAT('Static string: ',(`table2`.`Name`)))
```

The tables on both are identical (from my inspection :-/), `table1.View/Add/Edit` are `bit(1)` types and `table2.Name` is a `varchar(100)` with `charset=utf8mb4` and `collation=utf8mb4_unicode_ci`.

I can't figure out how the problematic instance ends up with `utf8mb4_bin` as the collation for the string result of the concat!

Comment: see the create table for both tables and you will find that table or columns have different collations.

Comment: why the CASTs?  what are those trying to accomplish?